# When to use C++ private inheritance over composition?

Tags: c++, inheritance, composition, strategy-pattern, private-inheritance

Can you give me a concrete example when is preferable to use private inheritance over composition? Personally, I will use composition over private inheritance, but there might be the case that using private inheritance is the best solution for a particular problem. Reading the [C++ faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/private-inheritance.html#24.3), gives you an example on using private inheritance, but I seems easier to use composition + strategy pattern or even public inheritance than private inheritance.

Comment: There are a million dups for this question. Perform a search. And, as you state, you already found an example. Just because you didn't like it doesn't make it not an example...

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943571/copying-methods-from-member

Comment: I think 'never' is the right answer...

Comment: Thanks, I did a search, but nothing showed up using the title strings, but I will rather use the template recursive pattern for this.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`private` inheritance is typically used to represent "implemented-in-terms-of". The main use I have seen is for mixins using private multiple inheritance to build up a child object with the proper functionality from the various mixin parents. This can also be done with composition (which I slightly prefer) but the inheritance method DOES allow you to use `using` to expose some parent methods publicly, and allows for a slightly more convenient notation when using the mixin methods.

Comment: You nailed it! I can see why private inheritance might lead to an easier solution... thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Scott Meyers in "Effective C++" item 42 says

> "Only inheritance gives access to protected members, and only inheritance allows for virtual functions to be redefined. Because virtual functions and protected members exist, private inheritance is sometimes the only practical way to express an is-implemented-in-terms-of relationship between
>   classes."

Answer (score 5):

### Privately inheriting interfaces

A typical application of private inheritance that many people overlook is the following.

```
class InterfaceForComponent
{
public:
    virtual ~InterfaceForComponent() {}
    virtual doSomething() = 0;
};

class Component
{
public:
    Component( InterfaceForComponent * bigOne ) : bigOne(bigOne) {}

    /* ... more functions ... */

private:
    InterfaceForComponent * bigOne;
};

class BigOne : private InterfaceForComponent
{
public:
    BigOne() : component(this) {}

    /* ... more functions ... */

private:
    // implementation of InterfaceForComponent
    virtual doSomething();

    Component component;
};
```

Usually `BigOne` would be a class with a lot of responsibilities. In order to modularize your code you would break your code into components, that help doing the little stuff. These components shouldn't be friends of `BigOne`, but still they might need some access to your class, that you don't want to give into the public, because it's implementation details. Hence you create an interface for that component to provide this restricted access. This makes your code better maintainable and to reason about, because things have clear boundaries of access.

I used that technique a lot in a several man-year project and it has paid off. Composition is not an alternative here.

### Letting the compiler generate a partial copy-constructor and assignment

Sometimes, there are copyable/movable classes that have a lot of different data members. The compiler generated copy or move constructor and assignment would be fine, except for one or two data members that need special treatment. This can be annoying, if data members are added, removed or changed frequently, since hand-written copy and move constructors and assignments need to be updated each time. It produces code-bloat and make the class harder to maintain.

The solution is to encapsulate the data members, whose copy and move operations can be compiler-generated into an extra `struct` or `class` from which you privately inherit.

```
struct MyClassImpl
{
    int i;
    float f;
    double d;
    char c;
    std::string s;
    // lots of data members which can be copied/moved by the 
    // compiler-generated constructors and assignment operators. 
};

class MyClass : private MyClassImpl
{
public:
    MyClass( const MyClass & other ) : MyClassImpl( other )
    {
        initData()
    }

    MyClass( MyClass && other ) : MyClassImpl( std::move(other) )
    {
        initData()
    }

    // and so forth ...

private:
    int * pi;

    void initData()
    {
        pi = &p;
    }
};
```

You can then use the compiler-generated operations of the `MyClassImpl` class in the implementation of the respective operations of the class you are interested in. You could do the same with composition, but this would uglify your code in the rest of your class. If you used composition, the rest of the implementation would have to suffer because of this implementation detail of the copy and move operations. Private inheritance avoids this and avoids lots of code repetition.

Comment: very interesting technique, though I am not sure i fully understand this, care to elaborate by adding a code that actually does something ? it would be really cool if you can provide an example that can run on http://cpp.sh/ to fully apreciate your code

Comment: @BinaryA The trouble is, that it't hard to find a reasonable code example, because the code needs some complexity for the pattern to be reasonable. For me the use case was GUI code where I have a widget class that has tons of functionality. This functionality is encapsulated into sub components where each can talk back to the widget through a different interface. The widget class inherits privately from these interfaces and implements them.

Comment: I just wanted to see how the call stack/sequence is performed, for example: what is the use of `~InterfaceForChild()` ? why the `~` before it ?which class is initialized and called by the client ?

Comment: @BinaryA That's seemingly a typo, it's probably supposed to be `~InterfaceForComponent`.

Comment: @Aidiakapi Thanks for the hint. Fixed it.