# Performance When Extending Classes, Composition vs Polymorphism

Tags: c++, oop

When extending a class, is there any difference in **performance** between polymorphism and composition? Take the following example using composition (in C++):

```
class Window
{
    public:
        Window(Renderer &renderer) : m_renderer(renderer)
        { }

        void update()
        {
            ....
            m_renderer.draw(this);
        }
    private:
        Renderer &m_renderer;
}
```

... and using polymorphism:

```
class Window : public Renderer
{
    public:
        virtual ~Window() {};

        void update()
        {
            ...
            draw();
        }
    protected:
        virtual void draw() = 0;
}
```

The composition version uses a reference as a member so I suppose that it requires a little more space, but is there any performance gain in either version?

Note: I have checked out similar post such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209019/private-inheritance-vs-composition-when-to-use-which), but is does not cover performance.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you pose the question like this, then *yes* there is a memory/speed trade-off.

*1. Composition*

- 8 bytes (on 64 bits architecture) are likely to be used for the reference

*2. Inheritance*

- 8 bytes (on 64 bits architecture) if you need to make your class polymorphic (v-pointer)
- some overhead for the attributes of the base class if any (note: inheriting from stateful classes is a code smell)
- ~20% overhead for the virtual call (gross estimate, lots of variation there)

So you might say that inheritance is slightly more costly... but really it's just invisible. The overhead of a function call compared to the inner computation required for graphic rendering is just negligible.

---

On the other hand, the *semantics* differ. Whether you inherit or not is significant. Is you `Window` a `Renderer` ? Does it make sense ?

Write **sane** code first. Then optimize as (if !!!) needed.

Comment: Inheritance means that the size of the class increasez by at least the size of the base class. It's not only the vftable that adds to the size, but the base class itself.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: yes, but I have no idea about the size of the `Renderer` class, for all I know it's stateless. Still, worth noting.

Comment: Well this size will anyway increase as much... Unless you share Renderer instances between different Windows.

Comment: @JensÅkerblom not if you use a reference.

Comment: @MatthieuM. a more correct statement would be that it increases by at least 8 bytes, not by 8. It's just misleading. You can't just assume it's stateless.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I have distinguished the v-pointer and the attributes so as the make it clear that one cannot be avoided.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore The size for composition version = size of window (including reference) + size of renderer. Size of polymorphic version = size of window (no reference) + size of concreate class (= size of renderer). So size difference should be 1 reference right?

Comment: The semantics can be changed (Renderer -> Renderable) to suit the situation.

Comment: @JensÅkerblom: That is spelling, not semantics. Semantics is about the meaning of the program. If the `Renderer` object should be shared between instances, then you cannot have each `Window` inherit from it (for example). If multiple classes inherit from `Renderable` then you have polymorphism: is it desired ? useful ? It's a question for you. Only you know what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you want the second version to be:

```
class Window : public Renderer
```

in which case, the memory by inheritance will actually be bigger. That's because, when you inherit something, the class increases in size by at least the `sizeof` the base class.

The first version actually only suffers a minor increase in size, as you're storing a reference and not an actual object. The following:

```
class Window
{
    public:
        Window(Renderer &renderer) : m_renderer(renderer)
        { }

        void update()
        {
            ....
            m_renderer.draw(this);
        }
    private:
        Renderer m_renderer; //no reference
}
```

would take up more space.

**More important** than anything when deciding between these two is not performance-wise (differences are minor, if at all), but the relationship between the two. Composition and inheritance describe different things.

If a `Window` **is a** `Renderer`, use inheritance. If a `Windows` **has a** `Renderer`, use composition.

Comment: True. But someone sometime told me "Reuse using composition". And here we can change the symancics to "Window" **is** "Renderable" vs "Window" **has a** "Renderer".

Comment: @JensÅkerblom are you reusing or extending the functionality?

Comment: Well the Window class is reused, and the update-method is extended so... both? But this is slightly outside the topic.