# multiple use of policies in policy-based design

Tags: c++, templates, policy-based-design

i have a class template `roundtrip` which takes two policies. as long as they are different, everything is fine, but using one policy twice leads to compilation errors.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class walk {
protected:
    void move() {
        std::cout<<"i'm walking."<<std::endl;
    }
};

class car {
protected:
    void move() {
        std::cout<<"i'm driving in a car."<<std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename S, typename T>
class roundtrip : private S, private T {
public:
    void printSchedule(void) {
        std::cout<<"away: ";
        S::move();

        std::cout<<"return: ";
        T::move();
    }
};

int main(void){
    roundtrip<walk,car> LazyTrip;
    LazyTrip.printSchedule();

    roundtrip<car,car> VeryLazyTrip; // ERROR: error: duplicate base type ‘walk’ invalid
    VeryLazyTrip.printSchedule();

    return 0;
}
```

how can that be resolved? or is there a better design to achieve the same behaviour?

EDIT: i added wrappers to the policies, the user interface does not change. what do you think about this solution, is it a clean design?

```
template<typename T>
class outbound : private T {
protected:
    void moveOutbound(void) {
        T::move();
    }
};

template<typename T>
class inbound : private T {
protected:
    void moveInbound(void) {
        T::move();
    }
};

template<typename S, typename T>
class roundtrip : private outbound<S>, private inbound<T> {
public:
    void printSchedule(void) {
        std::cout<<"away: ";
        this->moveOutbound();

        std::cout<<"return: ";
        this->moveInbound();
    }
};
```

Comment: "is it a clean design" might be a question more suitable for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). That said, some argue you should avoid private inheritance unless you need to use it (e.g. to override virtual functions); see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209019/private-inheritance-vs-composition-when-to-use-which) and this [C++FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/priv-inherit-vs-compos.html) (both for `outbound`/`inbound` and `roundtrip`, composition can be used).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of inheriting, you could add data members to `roundtrip`, but the functions in `walk` and `car` are currently `protected`. If you cannot make the functions in `walk` and `car` public, you could:

- befriend the `roundtrip` template

  ```
  class walk {
  protected:
      void move() {
          std::cout<<"i'm walking."<<std::endl;
      }
      template<class T, class S>
      friend class roundtrip;
  };
  ```
- make the member functions accessible to `roundtrip` via a helper class:

  ```
  template<typename S, typename T>
  class roundtrip {
  private:
      struct helperT : private T
      {
      public: // or private + friend roundtrip
          using T::move;
          using T::T;
      } mT;

      struct helperS : private S
      {
      public:
          using S::move;
          using S::S;
      } mS;

  public:
      void printSchedule(void) {
          std::cout<<"away: ";
          mT.move();

          std::cout<<"return: ";
          mS.move();
      }
  };
  ```

  If the interface is the same for both types, you could use a helper class template instead of two helper classes:

  ```
  template<typename S, typename T>
  class roundtrip {
  private:
      template<class U>
      struct helper : private U
      {
      public: // or private + friend roundtrip
          using U::move;
          using U::U;
      };

      helper<S> mS;
      helper<T> mT;

  public:
      void printSchedule(void) {
          std::cout<<"away: ";
          mT.move();

          std::cout<<"return: ";
          mS.move();
      }
  };
  ```

  (it is also possible to inherit from a helper template specialization, e.g. `class roundtrip : helperT<T>, helperS<S>`)

Comment: @DyP that solves the problem without touching the policies, nor the user interface. your last idea, is it the same as my EDIT example in the OP?

Comment: @the_ducky Yes; though I stopped at the idea of inheritance and didn't think of forwarding the member functions with different names to avoid ambiguities.

Answer (score 1):

As [noticed by DyP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982530/multiple-use-of-policies-in-policy-based-design/19982589#comment29748391_19982530) this is enough:

```
template<typename S, typename T>
class roundtrip {
    public:
    void printSchedule(void) {
        std::cout<<"away: ";
        awayPolicy.move();

        std::cout<<"return: ";
        returnPolicy.move();
    }

    private:
    T awayPolicy;
    S returnPolicy;
};
```

But this requires making `move` methods `public`. You can also make them `static` and `public`, so you won't need the instance fields:

```
class walk {
public:
    static void move() {
    std::cout<<"i'm walking."<<std::endl;
    }
};

// the same for car

template<typename S, typename T>
class roundtrip {
    public:
    void printSchedule(void) {
        std::cout<<"away: ";
        S::move();

        std::cout<<"return: ";
        T::move();
    }
};
```

You can also consider creating a base class:

```
class travelPolicy
{
public:
    virtual void move() = 0;        
    //...
};
```

with `car` and `walk` deriving from it. Then your `roundtrip` class can accept both policies through a constructor and using them in `printSchedule` via pointers.

```
class roundtrip 
{
public:
    roundtrip(
        std::shared_ptr<travelpolicy> awayPolicy,
        std::shared_ptr<travelpolicy> returnPolicy)
    {
        this->awayPolicy = awayPolicy;
        this->returnPolicy = returnPolicy;
    }


    void printSchedule(void) 
    {
        std::cout<<"away: ";
        awayPolicy->move();

        std::cout<<"return: ";
        returnPolicy->move();
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<travelPolicy> awayPolicy;
    std::shared_ptr<travelPolicy> returnPolicy;
};
```

**UPDATE** (responding to OP's edit):

Your solution is fine in general, however it still seems an overuse of inheritance. When `A` inherits `B` it is a way of saying that `B`'s *are* `A`s. Here surely it's not the case. The private inheritance "hack" makes this awkwardness invisible though, that's why it seems acceptable to me.

Comment: private inheritance is considered by some more like a *is-implemented-in-terms-of*-relationship. It might be useful if the base classes are empty, for example.

Comment: Thanks, @BartoszKP, these are working solutions. However, i would prefer not to change the policies, since they are potentially created by the user and should remain as simple as possible.

Comment: @the_ducky No problem. You'll find DyP's answer more helpful.

Comment: @DyP and BartoszKP : but then policy-based design always violates the _is-implemented-in-terms-of_-relationship, doesn't it?

Comment: @the_ducky Consider my last example - it uses the inheritance in an "OOP-correct" way, and it is considered policy based design.

Comment: @BartoszKP I see, it's "OOP-correct". However one might argue that it's not policy-based design any more since there is no compile-time configurable host class template any more.

Comment: @the_ducky Conceptually it's the same as a strategy pattern, and that's how I look at it. The infrastructural mechanism behind a particular design doesn't really matter. But strictly speaking you're right, and by definition the solution without compile-time resolution is not policy-based design.

Answer (score 0):

Why not specialize on the case of identical base classes?
If you can, I'd used boost's mpl::if_ instead of mine and c++11's or boost's type_trait's is_same.
I don't have a compiler handy, so there may be some syntax issues below

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename S, typename T>
class roundtrip_diff : private S, private T {
public:
    void printSchedule(void) {
        std::cout<<"away: ";
        S::move();

        std::cout<<"return: ";
        T::move();
    }
};

template<typename S>
class roundtrip_same : private S {
public:
    void printSchedule(void) {
        std::cout<<"away: ";
        S::move();

        std::cout<<"return: ";
        S::move();
    }
};

template<bool, typename True, typename False> struct if_{ typedef True type; };

template<typename True, typename False> struct if_<false,True,False> { typedef False type; };

template<typename A, typename B> struct is_same { enum{value=0}; };
template<typename A> struct is_same<A,A> { enum{value=1}; };

template<typename S, typename T>
class roundtrip : if_< is_same<S,T>::value, roundtrip_same<S>, roundtrip_diff<S,T> >::type { };
```

Obviously, a more elegant solution needs to be found when you allow an arbitrary number of arguments, but I think this should eliminate your error of duplicate bases.

Comment: @DyP yeah, except there's no C++11 tag on this.

Comment: `Why not specialize on the case of identical base classes?` That actually sounds like a job for partial specialization: `template<class T> class roundtrip<T,T> { /*...*/ };`

Comment: @KitsuneYMG: thanks, but spezialization is quite verbose here and - as you said - does not scale. nice to learn type_traits and std::conditional (DyP) though!

Comment: @the_ducky Take a look at Boost.MPL. You should be able to write a generic algorithm that can do this, replace Tn with T(n-1) if they are the same. It's just way more work than I was willing to put into a question that was explicitly about 2 base classes, especially as variadic templates is c++11 only and you're question is tagged [C++]