# Does a design pattern exist for enforcing rules on the data of a subclass?

Tags: c++, validation, design-patterns

Let's say a class represents a 3x3 matrix and takes 9 arbitrary numbers in its constructor and let that class have an inverse() method. Since NOT all matrices are invertible, the inverse() method returns an optional value (or a nullable pointer) which must be checked by callers at runtime.

However, certain 3x3 matrices are ALWAYS invertible, as long as the values in the matrix follow certain rules, e.g. 3D rotation matrices. We can codify that with a subclass, which does NOT allow direct construction but is constructed by using some special rules, e.g the rotation angle around a Cartesian axis.

The end result is this hierarchy, which should allow a client of the hierarchy to have compile time safety when using the subclass (e.g. a client is guaranteed that object.rotate(rotationMatrix.inverse()) will always work, assuming rotationMatrix is of type RotationMatrix):

```
class Matrix {
 public:
  Matrix(double e_0_0, double e_0_1, double e_0_2,
         double e_1_0, double e_1_1, double e_1_2,
         double e_2_0, double e_2_1, double e_2_2) {
      ...
  }

  std::unique_ptr<Matrix3x3> inverse() const {
    if (isInvertible) {
      return std::unique_ptr(new Matrix3x3(...));
    }

    return std::unique_ptr();
  }
}

class RotationMatrix : public Matrix3x3 {
 public:
  static RotationMatrix getRotationAroundX(double angle) {
    return asRotationMatrix(Matrix(1,          0,           0,
                                   0, cos(angle), -sin(angle),
                                   0, sin(angle), cos(angle)));
  }

  RotationMatrix inverse() const {
    return asRotationMatrix(*Matrix::inverse().get()));
  }

 private:
  static const RotationMatrix3D& asRotationMatrix(const Matrix3x3& matrix) {
    return static_cast<const RotationMatrix3D&>(matrix);
  }
}
```

So to break down the original question:

- is there a pattern other than the one described above to achive this functionality?
- if no other pattern exists, is there a way in C++ to prevent (or at least clearly signal to future developers) that the subclass MUST NOT introduce new state or constructors in order to avoid casting issues (e.g. slicing, etc)?

Comment: Not a design pattern, but you may as well throw an exception when `inverse()` is called on a matrix with a 0 determinant. If the matrix is constructed with constant values (not the case in your rotation matrix with calls to `cos` and `sin`), you may compute and test the determinant at compile time

Comment: Is your `Matrix` an immutable structure? If not, you're going to have problem with your code...

Comment: `optional` (`std::` in c++17, else `boost::`) would be a good replacement to `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 3):

Here, you hit the [circle/ellipse problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem):

Better to have to distinct classes  and use composition:

```
class RotationMatrix {
public:

    static RotationMatrix getRotationAroundX(double angle) {
        return { Matrix(1,          0,           0,
                        0, cos(angle), -sin(angle),
                        0, sin(angle), cos(angle))};
     }

     RotationMatrix inverse() const {
        return {*Matrix::inverse().get()});
     }

     const Matrix3x3& AsMatrix() const { return matrix; }

 private:
     static RotationMatrix(const Matrix3x3& matrix) : matrix(matrix) {}
     Matrix3x3 matrix;
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't `private` inheritance be better in C++ for this kind of stuff?

Comment: @Holt:Unless you require (private) inheritance, I would prefer composition. See [private-inheritance-vs-composition-when-to-use-which](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209019/private-inheritance-vs-composition-when-to-use-which)

Answer (score 0):

These constraints should be enforced through the interface, in this case through the constructors and any potentially available mutators (setters). This is very much the pattern you describe.

To prevent future developers from messing with the internals of your class through inheritance, make the relevant data members, i.e. those you want to protect, inaccessible by declaring them `private`.

Since C++11 you can also declare your class `final`, so that nobody can inherit from it at all.

Answer (score 0):

*is there a way in C++ to prevent (or at least clearly signal to future developers) that the subclass MUST NOT introduce new state*? Unfortunately the answer is NO. All the hierarchies in any OO languages use that as a common rule: *a subclass can do all what its parent does and can add other methods and attributs*

The better you can do if you have special requirements, is to write a documentation and clearly state them there.