# Composition over private inheritance

Tags: c++, composition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to use C++ private inheritance over composition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297331/when-to-use-c-private-inheritance-over-composition)

Please help me with a scenario where composition is preferred over private inheritance.

Comment: That would be almost any scenario that you can think of :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight...what are the tradeoffs of using private inheritance

Comment: You give up access control to some degree: when you inherit privately, you can *accidentally* access a protected method or member. [Here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/private-inheritance.html#faq-24.3) is a good discussion of the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the time. The real question is, when is private inheritance preferred over composition? Only when virtual functions are required. Else, always favour composition.