# Object Instantiations couting using composition in c++

Tags: c++, composition, private-inheritance

In More effective C++ Meyers has described a way to count the instantiation of the objects using an object counting base class (item 26). Is it possible to implement the same using composition technique as below . Is there a specific advantage using private inheritance and what are the drawbacks of using composition in this case.

ps:- I have reused the code from More effective C++ with small modification.

```
    #ifndef COUNTERTEMPLATE_HPP_
    #define COUNTERTEMPLATE_HPP_
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    template <class BeingCounted>
    class Counted {
    public:
        static int ObjectCount(){return numOfObjects;}
        Counted();
        Counted(const Counted& rhs);
        ~Counted(){--numOfObjects;}
    protected:
    private:
        static int numOfObjects;
        static int maxNumOfObjects;
        void init();
    };

    template<class BeingCounted> Counted<BeingCounted>::Counted()
    {
        init();
    }

    template<class BeingCounted> Counted<BeingCounted>::Counted(const Counted& rhs)
    {
        init();
    }

    template<class BeingCounted> void Counted<BeingCounted>::init()
    {
        if(numOfObjects>maxNumOfObjects){}
        ++numOfObjects;
    }

    class Printer
    {
            public:
        static Printer* makePrinter(){return new Printer;};
        static Printer* makePrinter(const Printer& rhs);
        Counted<Printer>& getCounterObject(){return counterObject;}
        ~Printer();
            private:
        Printer(){};
        Counted<Printer> counterObject;
        Printer(const Printer& rhs){};
    };

    #endif /* COUNTERTEMPLATE_HPP_ */
```

Comment: Private inheritance can make use of the empty base class optimization. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c68bae310c173e60)

Comment: Looks like your `init` implementation is invalid for the beyond maximum case

Comment: @icepack Yes.Actually it should throw exception. I have not added exception because my question doesn't depend on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is related to

- [Private inheritance VS composition : when to use which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209019/private-inheritance-vs-composition-when-to-use-which)
- [When to use C++ private inheritance over composition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297331/when-to-use-c-private-inheritance-over-composition)

Of those two, one is probably a duplicate of the other. But neither answers this question, and I'm somehow reluctant to post my answer to one of them.

---

Private inheritance can make use of the empty base class optimization:

```
class Printer0
{
    Counted<Printer0> counterObject;
    int m;
};

class Printer1 : Counter<Printer1>
{
    int m;
};
```

Clang++ and g++ both say `sizeof(Printer0) == 8` and `sizeof(Printer1) == 4`.

The reason is that data members have to have different addresses,
but a single empty base class does not need to use up memory in the object.
So `counterObject` is one byte large, and `int` is aligned to 4 byte,
therefore `Printer0` looks like this:

```
  | | X X |       | 
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
          ^~~~~~~~~ m
      ^~~~ padding
  ^~~~ counterObject
```

Answer (score 0):

Composition forces you to "pollute" the code of your class with the meta-data (i.e. counter object) that isn't related to its main business, in my opinion making the code less readable for this case. Also see @dyp answer regarding the technical aspect of empty class optimization.