# Helper struct to expose data member to public

Tags: c++, oop, non-member-functions

so I am trying to construct a class with helper method, namely:

```
class Type{
    int a, b, c;

    friend auto helper(auto);
    friend auto test_helper(auto);
    /* couples test with implement */

public:
    void method(){
        helper(this);
    }
};
```

But making `helper` a friend function couples the test with implementation if we want to test `helper`.

So I want to make `helper` a free function, namely:

```
auto helper(int&,int&,int&);
auto test_helper(int&,int&,int&);

class Type{
    int a, b, c;
public:
    void method(){
        helper(a,b,c);
    }
};
```

This, however, makes the code a lot more tedious when data members are many. So, I came up with an idea to construct an helper struct that has exact data member as `Type` but with all data member being public, so that we'll be able to simply pass in the handle of such `HelperType`, maybe something like:

```
struct HelperType{
    int a, b, c;
};
auto helper(HelperType* a);
auto test_helper(HelperType* a);
void Type::method(){
    helper(static_cast<HelperType*>(this));
}
```

Is there any elegant approaches to construct such `HelperType` struct? Such as a generic wrapper or perhaps with inheritance?

Comment: Best I can think of is doing something with `std::tuple` and a pack of variadic template parameter list.

Comment: Why don't you just make a getter functions for those values?

Comment: @VTT It is because those data member should not be publicly visible and also we want to have side effect on the data-member.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what do you mean?

Comment: You painted your problem in what I consider overly broad strokes, but I feel you have yourself an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe the helper is too complex? Maybe it's too complex because your design lacks the S in SOLID?

Comment: @StoryTeller I believe that is my exact problem. And it doesn't have to be a lot of parameters passed in to make them look tedious. I also don't want my question overly specified that give rise to some work around.

Comment: @TaylorHuang I mean that you could try an approach to bind the parameter variable types to the helper function using template meta programming and a variadic type parameter pack.

Comment: @TaylorHuang Here's a [similar thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251815/creating-an-array-initializer-from-a-tuple-or-variadic-template-parameters).

Comment: You can make those getters not publicly visible and mark functions that should access those getters as friends. I don't see any problem with having side effects on data members either.

Comment: "making helper a friend function couples the test with implementation" -> do you need this for unit tests? If yes, maybe `#define private public` in that test only would be an acceptable solution? It's not very elegant, but doesn't need any modifications of tested code.

Comment: @joe_chip
indeed I need that for unit test
this works of course but I would like to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

I have no simple solution to create `HelperType` from `Type` (only things coming to mind involve heavy metaprogramming or macro usage). However building `Type` from `HelperType` would be quite trivial, using `private` inheritance. From [Derived class (cppreference.com)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class):

> When a class uses private member access specifier to derive from a base, all public and protected members of the base class are accessible as private members of the derived class.

```
// Could be renamed "TypePrivateMembers" or "TypeData"
struct HelperType{
    int a, b, c;
};

auto helper(HelperType* a);

class Type : private HelperType {
public:
    // a,b,c can be accessed in Type class scope.

    void method(){
        helper(this);
    }
};
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ahNVFWLK7CHixmn2)

However, still from cppreference (emphasis mine):

> Private inheritance can also be used to implement the composition relationship (the base class subobject is an implementation detail of the derived class object). **Using a member offers better encapsulation and is generally preferred** unless the derived class requires access to protected members (including constructors) of the base, needs to override a virtual member of the base, needs the base to be constructed before and destructed after some other base subobject, needs to share a virtual base or needs to control the construction of a virtual base. [...]

This is the recurring [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) debate. This question has already been asked many times on StackOverflow, here are a few interesting link on the topic (in general & for this specific case):

- [Prefer composition over inheritance ? (language agnostic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)
- [When to use C++ private inheritance over composition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297331/when-to-use-c-private-inheritance-over-composition)